A new vector space? - Stuck proving $($*$)$ equation to prove $S_{a,b}$ is a vector space

 This is a continuation from this post. Check it out if you are interested.

Definition
Let $S$ be a finite subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that for all $i \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ we have that $s_i \leq s_{i+1}$ and $s_i \in S$.
We define the median of $S$ (denoted $\text{median}(S)$) as middle point of the sorted set in either decreasing or increasing manner. Example, the median of the set $\{2,3,1\}$ is $2$ because after ordering (which is "$1,2,3$"), the number $2$ is in the middle. If $S$ has an even amount of data (say $2k$ for some positive integer $k$), then the median of the set $S$ is $\frac{s_1 + s_2}{2}$ for some $s_1, s_2 \in S$.
$\\$
Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$. Set $$S_{a,b} := \left\{f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R} \mid f \in \mathcal{C}^{0}([a,b]) \,\ \wedge \,\ f \left(\frac{a+b}{2} \right) = f_{\text{median}} \right\}$$
where $\mathcal{C}^{0}(X)$ is the set of continuous functions on the nonempty set $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and if
$N$ is some fixed positive integer, define the sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ as
$$x_n = a + \frac{(b-a)n}{2N-1}$$
Finally, define the median of a function $f$ as
$$f_{\text{median}} := \lim \limits_{N \to \infty} \text{median} \{f(x_0), f(x_1), \cdots, f(x_{2N-1})\}$$
$\\$
Another equivalent definition for $f_{\text{median}}$ is the following: Let $f \in \mathcal{C}^{0}([a,b])$ and $f^{\rightarrow}(A) = \{f(a) : a \in A\}$ for any set $A$. If $g: f^{\rightarrow} ([a,b]) \to \mathbb{R}$ is the function such that
$$g(t) = \int_{a}^{b} |t - f(x)| dx$$
then
$$f_{\text{median}} := t_0 \iff g(t_0) = \min \limits_{t \in f^{\to}([a,b])} g(t)$$
$\\$
Another way to define it is to use the Lesbegue measure.
Let $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}), \lambda)$ be the Lesbegue measure space with respect to the Borel set $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and the Lesbegue measure $\lambda$. Then if $f \in \mathcal{C}^{0}([a,b])$ , then
$$f_{\text{median}} := \inf \left\{t \in f^{\to}([a,b]) : \lambda \left(\{x \in [a,b] \mid  f(x) < t\} \right) \geq \frac{b-a}{2} \right\}$$
Example #1
Let me give you an example with the Lesbegue measure. Let $a=-1$ and $b=1$ and $f: [-1,1] \to [0,1]$ such that $f(x) = x^2$.
Then, by definition of $f_{\text{median}}$, we wish to find the greatest lower bound for $t \in f^{\to}([-1,1]) = [0,1]$ such that the set of all $x \in [-1,1]$ such that $x^2 < t$ has lesbegue mesure not more than $\frac{1-(-1)}{2} = 1$. Therefore, $-1 \leq -\sqrt{t} < x < \sqrt{t} \leq 1$ or $x \in (-\sqrt{t}, \sqrt{t})$. Thus, $\lambda ((-\sqrt{t}, \sqrt{t})) = \sqrt{t} - (-\sqrt{t}) = 2\sqrt{t} \geq 1$. After solving for $t$, we have $t \geq \frac{1}{4}$. Hence, $f_{\text{median}} = \frac{1}{4}$.
Example #2
Now let's the same example as for Example #1 but with the integral definition. First, let's calculate the integral with $g(t)$. Then,
$$g(t) = \int_{-1}^{1} |t - x^2|dx = 2 \int_{0}^{\sqrt{t}} (x^2-t) + 2 \int_{\sqrt{t}}^{1} (t-x^2) dx = 2t - \frac{8t\sqrt{t}}{3} - \frac{2}{3}$$. Let's find now the derivative and set it to $0$.
$$g'(t) = 2 - 4\sqrt{t} = 0$$
Solving $t$ and checking if its the global minimum, and we get that $f_{\text{median}} = \frac{1}{4}$.
Fun Fact:
If $S$ is a nonempty finite subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and $-S := \{-s : s \in S\}$, then $\text{median} (-S) = - \text{median} (S)$ (why?).
Question
Is $V = S_{a,b}$ a vector space under the field $\mathbb{R}$ and the operation $(f+_{V}g)(x) := f(x) + g(x)$? I am trying to prove that for all nonempty subsets of the real numbers (finite cardinality) $A$ and $B$ satisfy:
$$\text{median}(A+B) = \text{median}(A) + \text{median}(B) \label{Med} \tag{$*$}$$
where $A+B = \{a+b : a \in A \wedge b \in B \}$.
Attempt

Identity: $zero(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. Note that ($zero$ is continuous on the interval $[a,b]$ because $zero$ is a polynomial), $zero(\frac{a+b}{2}) = 0$ and $zero_{\text{median}} = 0$ since

$$g(0) = \int_{a}^{b} |0 - 0| dx = 0(b-a) = 0$$ and $$\min \limits_{t \in zero^{\to}([a,b]) = \{0\}} g(t) = g(0) = 0$$

Inverse: If $f \in V$, then $(f)^{-1} := -f$. It is sufficient to show that $-f \in V$. If $f \in V$ then $f(\frac{a+b}{2}) = f_{\text{median}}$, so

$$(-f) \left(\frac{a+b}{2} \right) =-f \left(\frac{a+b}{2} \right) = -\lim \limits_{N \to \infty} \text{median}\{f(x_0), \cdots , f(x_{2N-1})\} = \lim \limits_{N \to \infty} \text{median}\{-f(x_0), \cdots , -f(x_{2N-1})\} = (-f)_{\text{median}}$$

Commutativity and associativity are trivial because on how the operation is defined.

Closure: Let $f, g \in V$. Then $f_{\text{median}}+g_{\text{median}} = (f+g)_{\text{median}}$ (why?) (this is where I get stuck because of $\eqref{Med}$) and (trivially) $f(\frac{a+b}{2})+g(\frac{a+b}{2}) = (f+g)(\frac{a+b}{2})$, so $(f+g)(\frac{a+b}{2})= (f+g)_{\text{median}}$.



$A=(1,5,9)$, $B=(1,2,12)$. Median of $A+B$ is median of $(2,3,6,7,10,11,13,17,21)$, which is $10$. Median of $A$ is $5$, median of $B$ is $2$, $5+2=7\ne10$.

Any thoughts on my comment, Joshua?

Good counterexample!

There are counterexamples. Here is a "small" one. Let $A=(1,2,5)$, $B=(1,3,8)$. Then median of $A$ plus median of $B$ is $2+3=5$, while
$$
A+B=(2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,13)
$$
with median $6\ne5$.
